# change the Column series display name dynamically in Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex

How to change the display name of the  column series of chart in flex, based on certain condition For (eg):
If the condition is year it should the year column series  else it should display the month series

```
`<mx:ColumnSeries displayName="YTD" fill="{sc11}" stroke="{s11}" yField="yearGrossCharge"/>

<mx:ColumnSeries id="month_id"  visible="false" includeInLayout="false"  displayName="Month" 
                                                 yField="grossCharge"/>
<mx:ColumnSeries id="year_id" displayName="year" includeInLayout="true" 
                                                 yField="grossCharge"/>`
```

I have tried by month_id.visible="False" but it doesn't work?? pls give  me some idea...

Answer (score 0):

The chart has a series array property, you should remove the series you do not want to display from this array. There is no built in support for this behaviour.